# Show integration lower bound

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose we know that

**Lemma** $(1 - y) ^ n \ge 1 - ny$ for all real number $0 \le y \le 1$ and natural number $n$.

Show that $\int^1_{-1} (1 - x ^ 2) ^ n dx \ge \frac{1}{\sqrt n}$. (Hint: for $|x| \le \frac{1}{\sqrt n}$ use the lemma; for $|x| \ge \frac{1}{\sqrt n}$ just use the fact that $(1 - x ^ 2)$ is positive. Prove it without using tigonometric substitution.)

In particular, why hint splitting $x$, since $x ^ 2 \in [0, 1]$?

Comment: is the first one meant to be $(1-y^n)$ or $(1-y)^n$?

Comment: Thanks, it's corrected.

Comment: The hints suggest possibly splitting the domain of integration over $$\left(-1,-1/\sqrt{n}\right)\cup\left(-1/\sqrt{n},1/\sqrt{n}\right)\cup\left(1/\sqrt{n},1\right).$$ What have you tried? (people are likely to mark you down if you don't show any working)

Comment: If you directly apply the Lemma you will get $\int_{-1}^{1} (1-x^{2})^{n}dx=2\int_0^{1} (1-x^{2})^{n}dx\geq 2\int_0^{1} (1-nx^{2})dx=2(1-\frac n 3)$ which yields nothing because $1-\frac n 3$ is negative for large $n$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the first one, prove it by induction on $n$.
When $n=1$, It's true trivially.

Then $(1-y)^{n+1}=(1-y)(1-y)^{n} \geq (1-y)(1-ny)=1-(n+1)y+ny^2\geq 1-(n+1)y.$

I believe this is called the Bernoulli Inequality.

For the second one:

Motivated by the hint, split the integral as suggested, and use the fact the $(1-x^2)^n$ is an even function to conclude that:

$\int^1_{-1} (1 - x ^ 2) ^ n dx= \int_{-1}^{\frac{-1}{\sqrt{n}}} (1 - x ^ 2) ^ n dx +\int_{\frac{-1}{\sqrt{n}}}^{\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}} (1 - x ^ 2) ^ n dx + \int_{\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}}^{1} (1 - x ^ 2) ^ n dx=2\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}} (1 - x ^ 2) ^ n dx + 2\int_{\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}}^{1} (1 - x ^ 2) ^ n dx \geq 2\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}} (1 - x ^ 2) ^ n dx  \geq 2\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}} (1 - nx ^ 2) dx =\frac{4}{3\sqrt{n}} \geq \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$.

The second to last inequality holds since, as suggested by the hint, $(1-x^2)^n \geq 1-nx^2 \geq 1-n(\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}})^2=1-1=0$, the integrad is positive.

Comment: I have carefully read your answer. I think you might meant that we can drop $2\int^1_{\frac{1}{\sqrt n}} (1-x^2)^ndx$, because $(1-x^2)^n$ is always positive. And use the lemma to make $2\int^{\frac{1}{\sqrt n}}_0 (1-x^2)^ndx \ge 2\int^{\frac{1}{\sqrt n}}_0 1-nx^2dx = \frac{4}{3\sqrt n}$?

Comment: Yes, That's what I meant. I've added a bit more detail.